# Installing SSL on a Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.0

Tags: ssl, iis-8

We are in the process of moving a website from a machine with Windows Server 2008 R2/IIS 7.5 to a machine with Windows Server 2012/IIS 8.0 (EC2 instance) as we want to take advantage of the new SNI feature.

This website has an SSL through Go-Daddy, so downloaded the corresponding files and followed their instructions found [here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4801/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-microsoft-iis-7) for IIS 7.0 since they don't have any available for IIS 8.0.

The problem that we are experiencing is that when we try to "Complete the Certificate Request" in IIS, it gives us an error message of `"Failed to Remove Certificate"`- we are not sure what certificate it is trying to remove.

In comparing them to Microsoft's instructions found [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability), we noticed during the import process when following Go-Daddy's instructions, it wants you to import the certificate into the "Intermediate Certification Authorities" directory which then places it in the Personal certificate store - but Microsoft's instructions say to import the certificate into the new Web Hosting certificate store.  Not sure if this may be part of the issue...

We thought maybe it was something to do with the certificate GoDaddy was issuing so we bought a brand new certificate for a different website from Thawte - however we are still getting the same error of "Failed to Remove Certificate".

Comment: duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/466266/installing-ssl-on-a-windows-server-2012-with-iis-8-0

Answer (score 0):

How are you requesting the certificate? Using Inet Mgr or typing MMC, adding certificates applet, then requesting the CSR?